# How to get code-coverage report for android test apk using jacoco?

Tags: java, android, code-coverage, jacoco

We have java lib which is used in unit tests(apk type), whitebox tests(apk type) and android samples(which are also used for automated tests). The task is to get code coverage report after automated test run all of these tests.

This java lib is built using special tool (not Eclipse, maven etc). All apk files are built using Ant.

How is it possible to get such report using Jacoco?
Is it possible to create total report which will be the result of merging reports for every test application?
Any tutorial or useful information will be appreciated.